# Qt - App crashes when adding item to QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to add item to a QTableWidge (by code) the app never runs. It shows the Program Crashed dialog and then quits. Here's the code I used:

```
QTableWidgetItem *something = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("A"));
ui->itemTable->setItem(1,1,something);
```

Comment: Show us some more code, because here all is correct.

Comment: There isn't any more code. Just the #include <QTableWidget>
Here is my design of the app: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11701729/Qt.png

Comment: And you are sure that you have inserted two rows in your table? Only reason of crushing your app is that you don't have this 1-st row or 1-st column

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I just tested out with other lists and it also crashes when I try to add item to QListView. :/

Comment: Did you put that code after the call to `ui->setupUi(this);` ?

Comment: Mm...no... :/ is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your code after `ui->setupUi(this)` because this function creates all widgets that you will use in your program. Your original code tries to insert the item into a non-existing widget (I mean it doesn't have allocated memory yet) and that's why your program is getting crushed.

It should be:

```
constructor
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    /* some code */
    QTableWidgetItem *something = new QTableWidgetItem(QString("A"));
    ui->itemTable->setItem(1,1,something);
    /* some code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use gdb to get your core backtrace and analyze what could be the problem.